# Homebrew Python Fab can't see yaml

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, fabric

I've installed several different versions of PyYAML at this point and in no instance does Fab see YAML.

I've done `brew install libyaml` and `pip install pyyaml` and in neither instance does fabric see the yaml module.

When I import YAML in Python, it works right. The result for `import yaml` and then `print(yaml)` is:

```
<module 'yaml' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/yaml/__init__.pyc'
```

Comment: How did you install fabric? What is the shebang line for the fabric command that you start. Please update your post with that information (leaving out any EDIT:/UPDATE: headers).

Comment: And it would help if you show the errors and/or the code in question.